# How to copy updated lines from another TortoiseSVN solution to my current solution?

Tags: c#, tortoisesvn

I am using Tortoise SVN. I want to update my solution using another solution. They have the same folder structure. Copy file if not exists. If there is conflict in file, I can update manually. Thank you.

Comment: It's not obvious to me what you're trying to achieve, and in what circumstances. Perhaps another tool, e.g. a three-way folder compare and merge tool, is better for that particular job.

Comment: I am creating an enhanced version of the solution in a separate SVN solution. However, I committed some changes on the old version. Now, I want to update my enhanced version with the changes in the old version. I am expecting some conflict, in which I prefer to see those and select the correct line of codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to create a new branch and add all those "another solution" files to it. Push those changes. Switch back to your development branch. Then merge that new branch you just created into your development branch!

If you use any client for source control, things would look pretty simple.